# 80's/90's YA horror book: girl sitting on a bathtub in which her twin/lookalike has drowned

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, horror

I have searched all of R. L. Stine's, and Christopher Pike's works as well, but I can not seem to find this book. It is a teen or young adult horror story from the late 80's or early 90's. I don't remember the title.

I remember a large, mansion-like hotel on the cover, in the distance, down a dirt road. In the foreground is the hotel's sign.

The only thing I remember from the story is the image in my mind of a girl sitting on the edge of an indoor hot tub with her hand in the water looking in. In the water, is a girl floating, face down, wearing the same clothes and with the same hair, possibly a twin or just a lookalike.

Comment: Are you sure that the story is science fiction or fantasy?  If so, why?  That detail may make it easier to recognize the story.